# UART communication problem between Raspberry Pi 4 and STM32F767ZI

Tags: stm32, raspberry-pi, uart

I'm trying to debug a problem with the UART communication between the raspberry pi 4 and an STM32.

Indeed, I try to send the number 1 from the raspberry pi to the stm32 but I can't get the right result.

Here is the code I implemented on the raspberry pi 4 :

```
    import serial 
    from time import sleep
    
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port = "/dev/ttyS0",
        baudrate = 9600,
        parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout = 1
        )  
data = 1  
    while True:
        data_str_list = [str(data)]
        send_string = ','.join(data_str_list)
        ser.write(send_string.encode())
        sleep(1)
```

Here is the STM32 code :

```
char data_sign[1];

int main(void)
{
  
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_DAC_Init();
  MX_UART4_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();

  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

      HAL_UART_Receive(&huart4, data_sign, sizeof(data_sign), 1000);

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

static void MX_UART4_Init(void)
{

  huart4.Instance = UART4;
  huart4.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart4.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart4.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart4.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart4.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart4.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart4.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart4.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart4.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

When I send 1, I get this with the STM32 debug:

[image]

Sometimes, the value is 241 but I don't know how to interpret this data.
Can you please help me please? I think it's a problem with the data types but I tried to change them but I still can't find the right result.

Comment: I would try to change char data_sign[1]; to char data_sign[2]; as the function HAL_UART_Receive takes a pointer to an array

Comment: I tried, but I got de same result.

Comment: Have you checked the return value from `HAL_UART_Receive`, to see if it really succeeds?

Comment: @Mat no it makes no difference, it will anyway be a pointer to an array. CristenTen are you sure you have the chip running at proper speed, and you have not mixed RS-232 with TTL level interfaces, so both are either RS-232 or TTL level devices?

Comment: @Klas-Kenny It returns 0 -> HAL_OKAY

Comment: @Justme Both chips have a baud rate of 9600 bit/s and are configured as UART output.

Comment: Start with known data such as the quick brown fox or whatever. Be sure you are receiving what you are sending. If you are you have initialized everything correctly and the hardware layer is OK. Do you have Tx of the transmitter connected to Rx of the receiver, if not swap the lines.